# Crash on device during a declare of ClientBase

Tags: .net, ios, wcf, xamarin.ios, sigabrt

I try to invoke a wcf web service in my MonoTouch application. On simulator all is working great. On device I received the error: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

I generate my proxy class using the tool: `SlSvcUtil.exe`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v3.0\Tools\SlSvcUtil.exe" /noConfig ...
```

The error occur when I create a new object of my `ClientBase`

Any idea ??

```
Dec 14 11:27:44 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1174] Builtin profile: container (sandbox)
Dec 14 11:27:44 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[1174] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/B40E6E7C-C0C5-4179-9DC5-96BA01962F28 [69] (sandbox)
Dec 14 11:27:46 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: Listened for connections from MonoDevelop for 2 seconds, nobody connected.
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: Ran out of trampolines of type 0 in '/private/var/mobile/Applications/B40E6E7C-C0C5-4179-9DC5-96BA01962F28/BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobilesBFRMSaleAssistantIOS.app/mscorlib.dll' (1024)
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: Stacktrace:
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:   at Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.Shared.LoginPresenter.<LoginAsync>m__4 (object,LoginCompletedEventArgs) [0x00010] in /Users/maboulianne/DEV/BFRetail/DEV/Mobiles/BFRMSaleAssistant/Shared/Presenters/LoginPresenter.cs:31
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:   at AuthenticationServiceClient.OnLoginCompleted (object) [0x00012] in /Users/maboulianne/DEV/BFRetail/DEV/Mobiles/BFRMSaleAssistant/Shared/AuthenticationService.cs:317
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.RunCompletedCallback (System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback,System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1/InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs<TChannel>) <0x0002b>
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1/<InvokeAsync>c__AnonStorey10.<>m__10 (System.IAsyncResult) <0x00147>
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: Native stacktrace:
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  0   BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x01011010 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 456
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  1   BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0103abe0 sigabrt_signal_handler + 168
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32dff539 _sigtramp + 48
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  3   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32df4f5b pthread_kill + 54
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  4   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32dedfeb abort + 94
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  5   BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x01161be8 monoeg_g_logv + 268
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  6   BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x01161c54 monoeg_g_log + 68
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  7   BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0100a7b4 get_numerous_trampoline + 416
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  8   BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0100aba8 mono_aot_create_specific_trampoline + 612
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  9   BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0101477c mono_create_specific_trampoline + 96
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  10  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x00ff6f78 mini_get_vtable_trampoline + 816
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  11  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x010ec248 mono_class_create_runtime_vtable + 3940
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  12  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x010eb1c0 mono_class_vtable_full + 292
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  13  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x010eb080 mono_class_vtable + 36
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  14  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x00ff2c1c mono_resolve_patch_target + 1028
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  15  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0100764c load_method + 1904
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  16  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x010090b0 mono_aot_get_method + 2940
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  17  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x00ff400c mono_jit_compile_method_inner + 108
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  18  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x00ff52ac mono_jit_compile_method_with_opt + 660
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  19  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x00ff54e4 mono_jit_compile_method + 52
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  20  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x010096b8 mono_aot_plt_resolve + 368
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  21  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x01013938 mono_aot_plt_trampoline + 88
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  22  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x00358d68 generic_trampoline_aot_plt + 136
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  23  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x003bac74 AuthenticationServiceClient_OnLoginCompleted_object + 448
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  24  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0001a638 System_ServiceModel_ClientBase_1_RunCompletedCallback_System_Threading_SendOrPostCallback_System_ServiceModel_ClientBase_1_InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs_TChannel + 44
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  25  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0001a9b0 System_ServiceModel_ClientBase_1__InvokeAsyncc__AnonStorey10__m__10_System_IAsyncResult + 328
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  26  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0031c71c wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 200
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  27  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x00ff66b0 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 2892
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  28  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x010ee85c mono_runtime_invoke + 200
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  29  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x01116e10 mono_async_invoke + 520
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  30  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x011199ec async_invoke_thread + 1060
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  31  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0111c504 start_wrapper_internal + 724
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  32  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0111c60c start_wrapper + 24
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  33  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0114926c thread_st
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  34  BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS 0x0117a8ac GC_start_routine + 136
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  35  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32db6c1d _pthread_start + 320
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>:  36  libsystem_c.dylib                   0x32db6ad8 thread_start + 8
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: =================================================================
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: used by your application.
Dec 14 11:27:49 unknown UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5][1174] <Notice>: =================================================================
Dec 14 11:27:50 unknown ReportCrash[1175] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS[1174]
Dec 14 11:27:50 unknown com.apple.launchd[1] <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:Bathfitter.Schemas.BFRetail.Mobiles.BFRMSaleAssistant.IOS[0x4ed5]) Job appears to have crashed: Abort trap: 6
Dec 14 11:27:50 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Warning>: Application 'Sale Assistant' exited abnormally with signal 6: Abort trap: 6
Dec 14 11:27:50 unknown ReportCrash[1175] <Error>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/BathfitterSchemasBFRetailMobileBFRMSaleAssistantIOS_2011-12-14-112750_iPhone-de-Marc-Andre-Boulianne.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
Dec 14 11:28:04 unknown wifid[30] <Error>: WiFi:[345572884.950223]: Client dataaccessd set type to background application
Dec 14 11:28:06 unknown CommCenter[17] <Notice>: No more assertions for PDP context 0.  Returning it back to normal.
Dec 14 11:28:06 unknown CommCenter[17] <Notice>: Scheduling PDP tear down timer for (345573186.105418) (current time == 345572886.105436)
Dec 14 11:28:06 unknown CommCenter[17] <Notice>: Client [com.apple.persistentconnection[apsd,60]] is telling PDP context 0 to go active.
Dec 14 11:28:06 unknown wifid[30] <Error>: WiFi:[345572886.202853]: Client dataaccessd set type to background application
Dec 14 11:28:50 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Dec 14 11:28:50 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
Dec 14 11:28:50 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: [AppleTSL2581] setPropertiesGated: requested ReportInterval=0 turn OFF sensor
Dec 14 11:28:50 unknown backupd[1179] <Warning>: INFO: Scheduling next backup at 12/14/11 11:06:30 PM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure without more details. A likely candidate is that you're hitting a code path that requires dynamic code generation (i.e. the JIT), something that is not possible under iOS devices (but working under the iOS simulator).

A stack trace of your crash would help us give you a more precise answer. You can get one by opening a terminal window and issuing the command:

```
\Developer\MonoTouch\usr\bin\mtouch --logdev
```

**UPDATE**

You log contains the string:

```
Ran out of trampolines of type 0
```

Which is a situation described in the MonoTouch's [troubleshooting](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/troubleshooting#Ran_out_of_trampolines_of_type_0) page. Simply add:

```
-aot "ntrampolines=2048"
```

to the **mtouch extra arguments** in your project's option and rebuild your application.